# How to COUNT number of occurrences of categories created Using CASE without sub-query in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, case

## Context

#### Question

- `order` table contain `id`,..., `total_amt_usd`,`account_id`
- `accounts` table contain `id`, `name`,...

Consider the above tables, I'd like to write an SQL query to:

1. Categories customers based on the amount associated with their purchases. The top category includes anyone with a total sales of all orders greater than 200,000 usd. The mid category is between 200,000 and 100,000 usd. The lowest category is anyone under 100,000 usd. Provide a table that includes the level associated with each account. The table should contain the account name, the total sales of all orders for the customer, and the category, and should be ordered with the top spending customers listed first.
2. provide the number of accounts associated with each of the categories created in part 1.

#### Answer

#### Part 1

```
SELECT a.name, SUM(o.total_amt_usd) AS total_amt_spent,
       CASE WHEN SUM(o.total_amt_usd) >= 200000 THEN 'top'
            WHEN SUM(o.total_amt_usd) >= 100000 AND SUM(o.total_amt_usd) < 200000 THEN 'mid'
            ELSE 'low' END AS category
FROM orders o
JOIN accounts a
ON a.id=o.account_id
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

#### Part 2

```
SELECT category, COUNT(category)
FROM (SELECT a.name, SUM(o.total_amt_usd) AS total_amt_spent,
             CASE WHEN SUM(o.total_amt_usd) >= 200000 THEN 'top'
                  WHEN SUM(o.total_amt_usd) >= 100000 AND SUM(o.total_amt_usd) < 200000 THEN 'mid'
                  ELSE 'low' END AS category
       FROM orders o
       JOIN accounts a
       ON a.id=o.account_id
       GROUP BY 1
       ORDER BY 2 DESC) AS table1
GROUP BY category;
```

---

## Inquiry

*Is there any way to do Part 2 without using sub-query?*
I have tried to include `COUNT()` in the same query but kept getting errors.

Comment: No, there is no way to do the second query without a "subquery".  Of course, that *could* be a CTE, temporary table, or possibly correlated subquery.  But you need two levels of aggregation.  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two levels of aggregation.  But you may not need the `join` to `accounts`:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT o.account_id, SUM(o.total_amt_usd) AS total_amt_spent,
             (CASE WHEN SUM(o.total_amt_usd) >= 200000 THEN 'top'
                   WHEN SUM(o.total_amt_usd) >= 100000 THEN 'mid'
                   ELSE 'low'
              END) AS category
       FROM orders o
       GROUP BY o.account_id
      ) a
GROUP BY category;
```

This assumes that the name is unique in the `accounts` table.

The `ORDER BY` is not appropriate in the subquery.  I also simplified the logic in the `CASE` expression, taking advantage of the fact that the conditions are evaluated sequentially.